# Typescript class extends from other class cannot be used as interface attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, extends

I am writing an object interface, one of which is **an attribute value is a class**. But ts compiler will **throw an exception when this class extends other classes**.

Here is a simple example:

```js
class Base {
    key: string
}

class Foo extends Base { }

interface Obj {
    list: Foo[]
    value: Foo
}

const obj: Obj = {
    list: [new Foo()],
    value: Foo // < Throws error here
}
```

The error content:

```
Property 'key' is missing in type 'typeof Foo' but required in type 'Base'.ts(2741)
test.ts(39, 5): 'key' is declared here.
test.ts(51, 12): Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?
```

And when I delete the extends in `Foo`, the error disappeared:

```js
class Foo { } // < delete extends here

interface Obj {
    list: Foo[]
    value: Foo
}

const obj: Obj = {
    list: [new Foo()],
    value: Foo // < No error throw
}
```

In my understanding, `Foo` extends from `Base`, so it should include the relevant attributes in `Base`, but the compiler tells me it does not.

So is there any way to solve this problem?

## Error with Generics

There is another question. When I use generics on `Obj` because there are multiple type extends `Base`. like this:

```
class Foo extends Base { }

class Bar extends Base { }

interface Obj<T extends Base> {
    list: Foo[]
    value: typeof T // < Throws error here
}

const obj: Obj<Foo> = {
    list: [new Foo()],
    value: Foo 
}
```

compiler will throw an exception as below:

```
'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Is there a way to make the generic definition a bit more complete?

### version I used

- node `12.16.1`
- typescript `3.8.3` and `4.3.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` in your `Obj` interface is an *instance* of the `Foo` class, not the class itself. So assigning an object whose `value` property is the `Foo` class to a variable of the interface type is an error. You should set `value` to an instance of `Foo` (such as `new Foo()`, which is what the compiler error message suggests), or if you really meant to use `Foo`, declare `value: typeof Foo` in `Obj`.

The reason this works when `Foo` does not extend `Base` is TypeScript's structural typing: `Foo` does not have any properties, so *any* object, including a class, can be assigned to a variable of that type, even though it may not be an actual instance of `Foo` at runtime.

**In response to the additional question regarding generics:**

`typeof T` is not valid when `T` is a type parameter, because `T` does not have to be a class. It can be an interface that is structurally compatible with `Base`, and interfaces do not have an "interface object" whose type can be retrieved with `typeof`. You could use this definition of `Obj`, which works but requires using `typeof` at use sites:

```js
interface Obj<T extends new (...args: any[]) => Base> {
    list: Foo[],
    value: T
}

const obj: Obj<typeof Foo> = {
    list: [new Foo()],
    value: Foo
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is correct, but I found a new question based on it. I have added to the above question, what do you think about it?